# Android: How to perform unit test for android fragment

Tags: android

I have an Android Tab Layout with swipeable views.

The file structure is as follows:

- There is an activity class: `TabMainActivity.java`
- Under this activity, there is a fragment class: `bookLockerFragment.java`

This fragment class is linked to an XML file which contains various buttons.

```
public class bookLockerFragment extends Fragment {
    Button btnSis;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_booklocker, container, false);
        btnSis = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnSis);
     }
 .......
 }
```

I have read up on vogella activity testing tutorials, but there is minimal information on unit testing for fragment.

I attempted to write some code but got stuck at this line:

```
transaction.add(R.layout.fragment_booklocker, fragment, "tag");
```

I get the following error:

> The method add(int, Fragment, String) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, booklockertest, String)

Code:

```
public class booklockertest extends
ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 < TabMainActivity > {

    private TabMainActivity mActivity;

    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

    public booklockertest() {
        super(TabMainActivity.class);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mActivity = getActivity();
    }

    private Fragment startFragment(booklockertest fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction =

        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.layout.fragment_booklocker, fragment, "tag");
        transaction.commit();
        getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
        Fragment frag =

        mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
        return frag;
    }

    public void testFragment() {
        booklockertest fragment = new booklockertest() {
            //Override methods and add assertations here.
        };

        Fragment frag = startFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

stumble upon this, and you probably have figured it out already, but

```
private Fragment startFragment(booklockertest fragment) { ... }
...
public void testFragment() {
    booklockertest fragment = new booklockertest() {
        //Override methods and add assertations here.
    };

    Fragment frag = startFragment(fragment);
}
```

should be

```
private Fragment startFragment(bookLockerFragment fragment) { ... }
...
public void testFragment() {
    bookLockerFragment fragment = new bookLockerFragment() {
        //Override methods and add assertations here.
    };

    Fragment frag = startFragment(fragment);
}
```